# Overflow cause content width wider than container

Tags: html, css, reactjs

What I want to achieve:
Make it possible to select which columns you should see in a table, and if you select "too many for the width to show", you should get a scrollbar to scroll horisontally.

So on a mobile device I have a `table` and a container that wraps around the it. The container is set to `overflow-y: scroll`.

The container is as wide as the mobile allows it, but when I add multiple columns so it overflows the with and cause a scroll, the content gets wider, as expected, but not that it pushes the whole content on my side. Should it not cut off the overflow in width? If not, how can I achieve that? (only getting scroll and keep the main width of the container)

Picture of what is happening (the start state was that the container was as wide as it could be on the screen): [image]

Comment: have you tried giving the containing element a maximum width along with the overflow property?

Comment: You have to give the container a `width` or `max-width`

Comment: The width/max-width does not help, since the containers width is as it should be, but the width of the content inside the container (the content that  is too wide) is too wide. Wider than the conainer. And this content width is causing the unwanted behavior

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly
You can can add these styles to make your table scrollable horizontally :

```
.classname {
         width:'as much as you need';
         overflow-y: hidden;
         overflow-x: auto;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I got the table scrollable, my problem was that the content inside the scrollable table made my whole page wider than the scrollable container itself, and I could not understand why